# How do I remove loadbalancer pollution from my access logs

Tags: logging, webserver, load-balancing, sun

I have a pair of Sun web servers (iws6) sitting behind a load balancer. It likes to know if the web servers are up and continually asks for /alive.html.
That is fine but how do I not log that in my access log?

Failing that, how could I have the archiver strip out that accesses when it roles the file over?

I would prefer something more elegant that cron calling grep -v alive.html

Answer (score 2):

You can give Apache rules about what logs to suppress. Maybe IWS has something similar?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#conditional

Answer (score 1):

Logs are usually one line per entry so that you can grep for what you want.  The idea is to have everything in the file, but to use grep in order to read the parts you care about.  Grep for everything but load balancer stuff when you read them.